# Android. ExpandableListView. CheckBox

Tags: android

Подскажите почему у меня в `ExpandableListView` в `GroupView` добавлены чек боксы, в чилдрен груп их нет, и при сворачивании/разворачивании списка находящегося над отмеченным чек боксом в приложении пропадает индикация этого чек бокса, при этом код работает как будто он выбран.

Я заметил взаимосвязь изображения отмеченных чек боксов от количества строк в `GroupView`, как будто они смещаются на количество строк в `GroupView`. Например если отмечен второй `GroupView`, а в первом есть одна строка, то при её разворачивании чек бокс становится не отмеченным, при обратном сворачивании он снова отмечен. А если отмечены второй и третий `GroupView`, то при разворачивании первого остается отмечен только второй чек бокс.
 Но если в `GroupView` больше 1 выпадающей строки, то  может начаться полный хаос.
Как мне исправить этот кошмар, что бы отмеченные чек боксы оставались отмеченными там где их отметили?
Должно же быть какое то простое решение что то типа  `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"`

Адаптер:

```
    public class ListView extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<Block> list;
private List<SortedMap<String ,String>> mapList = new ArrayList<>();
private SortedMap<String, String> map;

public ListView(Context context, List<Block> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    Collections.sort(this.list, new Comparator<Block>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Block o1, Block o2) {
            return o2.getDate().compareTo(o1.getDate());
        }
    });

    if (list.size()>0){
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            map = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return o1.compareTo(o2);
                }
            });
            map.putAll(list.get(i).getMap());
            mapList.add(map);
        }
    }
    initCheckStates(false);

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    CheckBox checkbox;
}

TotalListener mListener;

public void setmListener(TotalListener mListener) {
    this.mListener = mListener;
}
ArrayList<Boolean> selectedParentCheckBoxesState = new ArrayList<>();

public List<SortedMap<String ,String>> getMapList() {
    return mapList;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return list.get(groupPosition).getMap().size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return list.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    map = mapList.get(groupPosition);
    String[] s = new String[2];
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String ,String > m :map.entrySet()){
        if (i == childPosition){
            s[0] = m.getKey();
            s[1] = m.getValue();
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return s;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    String listTitle = "Язык блока: " + list.get(groupPosition).getLanguage() +
            "\nДата создания: " + list.get(groupPosition).getDate() +
            "\nСледующие повторение: " + list.get(groupPosition).getDate();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main, parent,false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cch1);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.text.setText(listTitle);
    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean state = selectedParentCheckBoxesState.get(groupPosition);
            selectedParentCheckBoxesState.remove(groupPosition);
            selectedParentCheckBoxesState.add(groupPosition, !state);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            showTotal();
        }
    });

    holder.text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.expandGroupEvent(groupPosition, isExpanded);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String[] s = (String[]) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    String key = s[0];
    String value = s[1];

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);
    }
        TextView expListTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem1);
        expListTextView.setText(key);
        TextView expListTextView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem2);
        expListTextView2.setText(value);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public List<Block> getList() {
    return list;
}

public SortedMap<String, String> getMap(int i) {
    return mapList.get(i);
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void initCheckStates(boolean defaultState) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++) {
        selectedParentCheckBoxesState.add(i, defaultState);
    }
}

private void showTotal() {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < selectedParentCheckBoxesState.size(); j++) {
        if (selectedParentCheckBoxesState.get(j)) {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    mListener.onTotalChanged(sum);
}
```

И кусок кода Main:

```
      public void list(View view) {
    vv1 = view;
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    ExpandableListView expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);
    expListAdapter = new ListView(this, creater.getList());

    expListAdapter.setmListener(this);
    expListView.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

    registerForContextMenu(expListView);

    expListView2 = expListView;
    }

      @Override
public void onTotalChanged(int sum) {
    System.out.println("AAAAA " + sum);
}

@Override
public void expandGroupEvent(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded) {
    if(isExpanded) {
        expListView2.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
    }
    else {
        expListView2.expandGroup(groupPosition);

        expListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте код вашего адаптера

Comment: добавил  код адаптера и чуток из Main

Answer (score 0):

Я чуть с ума не сошел!!! Но я сделал костыль для решения этой проблемы!

```
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    String listTitle = "Язык блока: " + list.get(groupPosition).getLanguage() +
            "\nДата создания: " + list.get(groupPosition).getDate() +
            "\nСледующие повторение: " + list.get(groupPosition).getDate();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main, parent,false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cch1);
        holder.num = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ww1);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    if (selectedParentCheckBoxesState.get(groupPosition)) {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
    }else holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
    ...............
    ...............
```

Правда анимация установки и снятия флажков в местах где их быть не должно осталась.